# How to choose random move that takes highest value piece in chess?

Tags: java

So I have an array list of all the moves at the current board state in chess that take a piece.

```
ArrayList<Move> takePiece;
```

And all the pieces have a corresponding value:

```
  public static final int PAWN = 1;
  public static final int KNIGHT = 2;
  public static final int BISHOP = 3;
  public static final int ROOK = 4;
  public static final int QUEEN = 5;
  public static final int KING = 6;
```

I want to be able to select a random move from the array list that takes the highest value piece.

So if 3 different moves could take the king it would randomly choose one of the 3 moves (check and checkmate haven't been implemented).

How would i go about this?

```
public Move(Piece p , int x, int y, int dx, int dy, boolean t){
        this.p = p;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
        this.t = t;             
    }
```

So this is what a move is so to check the piece value that was going to be taken i would check the piece at (dx,dy).

Comment: how you refer to your pieces in `Move`?

Comment: @JordiCastilla I've updated the question for you

Comment: Piece has something like `getType()` ?

Comment: @JordiCastilla `PieceCode.charToInt(test.getChar())` if the Piece is called `test`.

Comment: check my answer... why getChar if you have piece constants as int??

Comment: @JordiCastilla a lot of the code was already provided and thats the only way to get a pieces char code.

Comment: updated answer with `PieceCode.charToInt(m.getChar())` but I guess you get the idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check in your array the most valuable `Piece` and choose your move accordingly, to make this, you must iterate twice:

```
// get the max value of possible pieces that could be taken
ArrayList<Move> takePiece // here you must have all possible takes
int maxPieceValue = 0;
for (Move m : takePiece) {
    if(PieceCode.charToInt(m.getChar()) > maxPieceValue)
        maxPieceValue = m.getPiece.getType();
}

// get a list with best moves available
ArrayList<Move> bestMoves new ArrayList<Move>();
for (Move m : takePiece) {
    if(PieceCode.charToInt(m.getChar()) > maxPieceValue)
        bestMoves.add(m);
}

// choose randomly one of best moves
Random random = new Random();
Move choosenMove = bestMoves.get(random.nextInt(bestMoves.lenght));
```